# Unexpected output in this program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[20];
    printf("\nEnter your name: ");
    gets(arr);
    printf(arr);
}
```

Input: `%d%s%u`

Output: `0<null>-056716812[`

Why is the output like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` writes the output under the control of a `format string` that specifies how subsequent arguments (or arguments accessed via the variable-length argument) are converted for output.

If the number of arguments provided in `printf` call are less than the number of conversion specifiers, then the behavior is undefined.

This is how the call should be made, `printf("%s",arr)`.

By the way, there is something even funnier you might want to try which is - `printf(arr,20,arr,20)` - replace it and see the fun, but make sure the input is still the same that you gave, i.e., `%d%s%u`

Comment: Something which the Standard is not bothered to tell us about, read it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 4):

You probably haven't come across formatted output yet. `printf()` takes a string as its first parameter and then a variable number of extra parameters. Special strings found in the first parameters are replaced by the values provided in the extra parameters. For example:

```
int i = 42;
printf("%d", i);
```

outputs 42.

Or you could write:

```
char name[] = "The Devil";
int num = 666;
printf("My name is %s and my favourite number is %d.", name, num);
```

Well, you can imagine what happens.

Now if you look back at your problem, it's easy to see what is happening.  You are effectively writing:

```
printf("%d%s%u");
```

but since you don't provide any values for the 3 placeholders, the result is garbage - technically known as *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Well i do know about formatted output. My question was regarding the inputs .. i was expecting the code to not compile in the 1st place.

Comment: @Lohit:: Its supposed to take variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`gets` is not safe. It doesn't check buffer overflows. Use fgets instead.

```
fgets(arr,sizeof(arr),stdin) ;
```

And print -

```
printf("%s", arr) ;
```

Comment: ya i know. the question isn't about that. i was wondering why printf behaved like that.

Comment: @Lohit - When you know it is unsafe, why are you using it ? Don't you think it is suicidal ?

Comment: Mahesh this is just a test program. Relax, no one will hack my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to use printf, you should do `printf("%s", arr);` to print a string from the place pointed by arr. The way you called it, it was actually called `printf("%d%s%u");` which gave you a garbage, depends on the calling convention, you will get different results. in case of [cdecl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) it will print the next element on the stack as int, then the string pointed by the following element and then the next element as an unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wanted to use the counterpart of `gets`, which is `puts`:

```
puts(arr);
```